# Directions to marker with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm using the Google Maps API and currently I have a custom marker that highlights the location. What I would like to do, if possible, is be able to click it and have it bring up the google maps directions dialog (e.g [THIS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp2xmg2599xuyc3/Screenshot%202015-01-04%2012.20.35.png?dl=0)) that you get when clicking on a place name normally on google maps. At the minute I've just set it to zoom in on the marker, but obviously I'll just get rid of that function if I can get this to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(50.871622, -4.131561);  

    var mapOptions = {
      center: location,
      zoom: 11,
      scrollwheel: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    var image = {
        url: 'img/mapmarker.png',
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: image,
        title: 'Deer Park Dairy'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      });

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to send the user to [google maps](http://maps.google.com), or [generate the directions on your API based map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)? [example sending to google maps](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4.html) - [example using the API directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html)

Comment: I want to generate directions on my map. Sorry I have already seen that section you linked to, I'm just really struggling to understand it. What I want to do is have the user click on my marker and then have the map offer the user directions to the marker from either a location that they input or "current location" like it does when you're on google maps normally.

Comment: Oh wow I just noticed your other links. the "example using the API directions service" would be perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code with the directions handling from [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html).  The original functionality was written by [Mike Williams for the Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm) (which is now deprecated and turned off). So this Javascript is based on code provided by the Community Church Javascript Team (http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/, http://econym.org.uk/gmap/)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4heod2ck/)

[image: screenshot of fiddle]
code snippet:

```js
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var htmls = [];

// arrays to hold variants of the info window html with get direction forms open
var to_htmls = [];
var from_htmls = [];

// global "map" variable
var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});


function initialize() {

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(50.871622, -4.131561);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: location,
    zoom: 11,
    scrollwheel: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  var image = {
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: image,
    title: 'Deer Park Dairy'
  });

  var i = gmarkers.length;
  latlng = location;

  // The info window version with the "to here" form open
  to_htmls[i] = html + '<br>Directions: <b>To here<\/b> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>' +
    '<br>Start address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
    '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br>' +
    '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="button" onclick="getDirections()"><br>' +
    'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" id="daddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
    '"/>';
  // The info window version with the "from here" form open
  from_htmls[i] = html + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <b>From here<\/b>' +
    '<br>End address:<form action="javascript:getDirections()">' +
    '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br>' +
    '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT"><br>' +
    'Walk <input type="checkbox" name="walk" id="walk" /> &nbsp; Avoid Highways <input type="checkbox" name="highways" id="highways" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" id="saddr" value="' + latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng() +
    '"/>';
  // The inactive version of the direction info
  var html = marker.getTitle() + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here<\/a> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here<\/a>';
  var contentString = html;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  htmls[i] = html;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// ===== request the directions =====
function getDirections() {
  // ==== Set up the walk and avoid highways options ====
  var request = {};
  if (document.getElementById("walk").checked) {
    request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
  } else {
    request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("highways").checked) {
    request.avoidHighways = true;
  }
  // ==== set the start and end locations ====
  var saddr = document.getElementById("saddr").value;
  var daddr = document.getElementById("daddr").value;

  request.origin = saddr;
  request.destination = daddr;
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("Directions not found:" + status);
  });
}


// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}


// functions that open the directions forms
function tohere(i) {
  // gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(to_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.setContent(to_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}

function fromhere(i) {
  // gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(from_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.setContent(from_htmls[i]);
  infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);
}

// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
// from the v2 tutorial page at:
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm
```

```css
html,
body,
table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
td,
tr {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="directionsPanel"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API has been updated and now, when you get your bearing updates, you can do the following:

```
val position = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(position).title(title).icon(icon).flat(true).
              rotation(heading.toFloat()))
```

Don't forget to flat your marker. It ensures the marker is north aligned so that the bearing will work correctly even if the user rotates the map.