# Highlighting marker in Google Maps Api 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a map using [this code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable).

But, I like create a button equal to the created by Google Maps ? For example, when you click in `<a href="#">Show Cocklebiddy WA Waypoint B</a>` on the map highlight the waypoint B

Example, On click in maker A or B:
[image]

Show the maker:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can create my own custom button ?

Comment: don't really understand your question. but you can change the style of the marker. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765446/directions-to-marker-with-google-maps-api